# How do I get data in my model from View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is the view code, I am using TimeSheetView Model (Which is mentioned below). I want to store a Task with date and number of hours. Please help me if possible, I will be very Thankful to you. Should I change I change my Model?

```
    @model Authentication.Models.TimeSheetViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Time Sheet";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Time Sheet</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TimeSheet", FormMethod.Get))
{

   var date_0 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday);

<style>
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 10.79193%;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .row::after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;

    }

    input {
        width: 90%;
    }
</style>
```

here I am creating the heading for date and task

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <h4>Task</h4>
    </div>
    @for (int dates = 0; dates < 7; dates++)
    {
        <div class="column">
            <h4>@date_0.AddDays(dates).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</h4>
            <h4>@date_0.AddDays(dates).DayOfWeek</h4>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

here i am creating the textboxes and storing its data in the model.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                <div class="column">
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TaskDetails[j].Task)
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="column">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TaskDetails[j].Hours)
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
}
<input type="submit" />
}
```

This is model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Authentication.Models
{
public class TimeSheetViewModel
{
    public List<TaskList> TaskDetails { get; set; }
}
public class TaskList
{
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
}
}
```

Should I Change my model?

[image: Please see my view]

Comment: your model seems right. you just need to write appropriate post action method to bind the posted data

Comment: public actioname(TaskDetails[] TaskDetails){}

Comment: On submit, I am getting the data of first row textboxes only. I am unable to figure out this.

Comment: I changed my task, hours and TaskDate as array in my model, and now it is working.